# How can I create a 2-dimensional array in PowerShell Core 7.3, assign just the first row and address elements with 2 indices?

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array

I want to create a 2-dimensional array in PowerShell Core 7.3 and assign just the first row:

```
$A = @(@( "Pink", "Yellow", "Orange", "Green", "Blue"))
```

Then I try to retrieve the 3rd element ("Orange"):

```
$A[0][2]
```

Output: `n`

It actually put all  values in separate rows:

```
$A[0] is "Pink"
$A[1] is "Yellow"
etc.
```

The 2nd index will address the nth character in that row:

```
$A[0][0] is P
$A[0][1] is i
$A[0][2] is n
$A[0][3] is k
```

However, if I initialize the array with 2 rows, everything works as expected:

```
$A = @( @("Pink","Yellow","Orange","Green","Blue"), @("Hearts","Stars","Moons","Clovers","Diamonds"))

$A[0][2] is "Orange"
$A[1][3] is "Clovers"
```

How can I have just row 0 populated and still address each element with 2 indices like `$A[0][…]`?
How would I initialize a new array with just one row of constant columns?

Comment: `$A = @(, @( "Pink", "Yellow", "Orange", "Green", "Blue"))` you need a comma before the inner array